# ggplot2: Legend Overlays Panel Border

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I want to create a plot via the ggplot2 package with the theme_bw and a legend at the topright of the plot. Unfortunately, the legend overlays the border of the plot. Consider the following example in R:

```
library("ggplot2")

# Example data
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10,
                 y = 1:10,
                 col = as.factor(c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5))))

# Plot
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, col = col)) + 
  geom_line() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.position = c(1, 1),
        legend.justification = c(1, 1))
```

**Question: How could I keep the black border around the plot?**

Comment: Slightly hacky, but if you adjust the legend position just a little bit, you can nudge the legend inside the plot. With the position (1,1), the legend corner is exactly the same as the plot's corner, giving you that overlap. With (0.99,0.99), it's just inside the border.

Comment: @camille Thanks! I will do it like that.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following line to your call to `theme`:

```
    ,legend.background = element_rect(fill = NA)
```

Comment: Thanks, the border remains black with your code. However, the background of the legend is not white anymore. Is there any way to keep the background of the legend white and still keep the border of the plot?